# Text moves when parent element is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a h1 tag in a div that is centred using text-align. The div is centred using margin: auto. I have JQuery that is changing the width of this div but, upon this re-sizing, the text moves to the right a bit. This also happens with the (also centred) menu bar I have below it. This is the code from the JSFiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu"><a class="active" href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a                href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a                href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a                href="#">Text</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a                href="#">Text</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = $("div");
    div.fadeTo(0, 0);
    div.fadeTo(1000, 1);
    div.animate({width: '+=2%'}, 250);
    div.animate({width: '-=2%'}, 500);
});
```

*For brevity, the css is committed from the post but is on the JSFiddle*

What is causing this? And how can it be avoided? There is nothing in the CSS that could affect the width or positioning of anything independently.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5vtvzsgc/

Comment: How so? List the problems and I will try and fix them.

Comment: @OlieAyre Try doing another fiddle or use the code utility here on SO. On JSFiddle there is a gear icon where you can denote that you are using jQuery. Or at the very least, provide the code sample here.

Comment: try to get your fiddle working to attract attention to your question.  Click 'javascript' in the top right of the script panel, and select a jQuery version.

Comment: Code added, JSFiddle fixed, happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are changing the width of all divs on the page. To fix this simply change the width of your outer div `content`, so change this line:

```
var div = $("div");
```

To this:

```
var div = $("#content");
```